# Tensorflow softmax returns 1 or 0 instead more wide probability

Tags: tensorflow, convolution, softmax

```
   x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3])     # 128

    W_conv1 = tf.get_variable("W_conv1", shape=[3, 3, 3, 64], initializer=xavier())
    b_conv1 = tf.get_variable('b_conv1', [1, 1, 1, 64])
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
    h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)                             # 64

    W_conv2 = tf.get_variable("W_conv2", shape=[3, 3, 64, 128], initializer=xavier())
    b_conv2 = tf.get_variable('b_conv2', [1, 1, 1, 128])
    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
    h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)                             # 32

    W_conv3 = tf.get_variable("W_conv3", shape=[3, 3, 128, 256], initializer=xavier())
    b_conv3 = tf.get_variable('b_conv3', [1, 1, 1, 256])
    h_conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool2, W_conv3) + b_conv3)
    h_pool3 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv3)                             # 16

    W_conv4 = tf.get_variable("W_conv4", shape=[3, 3, 256, 512], initializer=xavier())
    b_conv4 = tf.get_variable('b_conv4', [1, 1, 1, 512])
    h_conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool3, W_conv4) + b_conv4)
    h_pool4 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv4)                             # 8

    W_conv5 = tf.get_variable("W_conv5", shape=[3, 3, 512, 512], initializer=xavier())
    b_conv5 = tf.get_variable('b_conv5', [1, 1, 1, 512])
    h_conv5 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool4, W_conv5) + b_conv5)
    h_pool5 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv5)                             # 4

    h_pool5_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool5, [-1, 4 * 4 * 512])

    W_fc1 = tf.get_variable("W_fc1", shape=[4 * 4 * 512, 4096], initializer=xavier())
    b_fc1 = tf.get_variable('b_fc1', [4096], initializer=init_ops.zeros_initializer())
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool5_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

    W_fcO = tf.get_variable("W_fcO", shape=[4096, 2], initializer=xavier())
    b_fcO = tf.get_variable('b_fcO', [2], initializer=init_ops.zeros_initializer())

    logits = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fcO) + b_fcO
    y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(logits)


    cross_entropy = loss_ops.softmax_cross_entropy(logits, y_)

    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0005).minimize(cross_entropy)

    self.results = predictions = tf.argmax(y_conv, 1)

    self.probabilities = y_conv

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(predictions, tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

I have only 2 classes. My batch was 32K positive and 32K negative images (128x128). I ran for 80 epochs. Testing neural network for positive / negative was very promising. I've ran another batch of tests on my computer. Ran 500 negative pictures with 8% false positive result and 200 positive images with 9% false negative result.

The problem occurred when I've tried checking probabilities. Softmax is returning for each class mainly 1.0 or 0.0. Shouldn't it be like 0.745 / 0.255 something like that.

Even though it classifies images pretty well, softmax returns too dense results. Where is my mistake?

Comment: I think it's not necessarily a bad thing. It indicates the inherent uncertainty of the data and you can always find what's the most probable classification. But, if you want, you can force less sparse results by multiplying the values by a constant just before the softmax.